# How to follow dynamic paint brush direction with object in Blender V2.80 beta and 2.79b?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I am floating this boat on an ocean, created with the ocean modifier. I use dynamic paint to move the boat on the surface of the water with the help of a 'cage' which contains the boat inside it, with constrains. The 'cage' is the brush, of course, and the ocean is the canvas for the dynamic paint.
See image below.

[image]

I animate the 'cage' and the boat follows on the surface of the ocean. The problem is that when I animate the 'cage' to turn, the boat does not turn with it, only follows the original heading and moves sideways with the 'cage'. The animation below shows after turning from the straight movement but still follows original direction.

How can I make the boat turn with the 'cage'?

[image]

Just a note: I do not see the dynamic brush paint on the dynamic canvas, unlike in V2.79, not sure if that should be reported as a bug.

Since the initial writing of this question, I have tried to do the same in Blender V2.79b and I have the same problem there too, see image below with the ocean Surface canvas view and render. It shows the 'cage' and the boat facing to 2 different directions and from the render you see that it is sliding creating the froth towards the top of the screen. Obviously I am missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like nobody could help me with this one. I managed to come up with a solution for this but with a bit different method. It works in both Blender V2.79b and V2.80 Beta. I added a path to make nicer turns but finally the turns are happening.
The following was setup, additionally, to get an object to follow the waveform of the ocean while it moves around the surface:

1. A path was added - in this case a BezierCircle in the Outliner called 'BezierCircle - Path to follow' and animated.
2. Added a Plane and subdivided it 2 times in Edit mode. 'Called Plane on water surface' on the image below. Added a Shrinkwrap modifier to it and set the target to be the 'Ocean', that mowed the plane to the ocean surface. Added an Object Constraint and the target was the 'BezierCircle - Path to follow' object. Ticked the Follow Curve
3. The 'Boat -constrained to Plane on water surface' object added a Copy Location and a Copy Rotation constrains. Both have the target set to 'Plane on water surface' object and it Vertex Group selected to 'Group' that was defined for that plane.

[image]

The purple plane on the bellow image is the 'Plane on water surface' object that follows the waves with the Shrinkwrap modifier and the boat is constrained to it with Location and Rotation. The orange path is the one the 'Plane on water surface' object follows.

[image]

This is a tight turn but demonstrates that the turning direction is followed.

[image]

The same section of the path but with material applied. This is not baked or animated yet, only played.

[image]